# Error: Invalid field selected for SObject OpportunityLineItem

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

Can any one help me out on this Error: Invalid field selected for SObject OpportunityLineItem.
This is a page created for multiple row to edit.Any suggestion plz.
Here is the VF page :

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:pageBlock Title="ALL OPPORTUNITY PRODUCTS FOR ROW EIDTING">
       <!--saving editing value -->
       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!tosave}" id="saveButton"  />

       <apex:outputPanel style="float:middle">

      <!--display pageblock table.....-->

          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OpportunityLineItem}" var="o" cellpadding="2" border="1"  rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" id="opp_table">
              <apex:column headerValue="All OpportunityProduct Name" >

                 <!--displaying checkbox inside column...-->

                 <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!o.selected}">

              <!--invoking a controller function to know selected contacts.....-->

                   <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getSelected}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                 </apex:inputcheckbox>&nbsp;
                <b><apex:outputField value="{!o.opp.product2.productcode}"/> </b>    

               </apex:column>

             <apex:column headerValue="QUANTITY" > 
                <apex:outputfield value="{!o.opp.Quantity}" /> 

             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="SALES PRICE"> 
               <apex:outputField value="{!o.opp.Unitprice}"/>
             </apex:column>

            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"  showOnEdit="saveButton"/>

     </apex:pageBlockTable>

  </apex:outputPanel>

 </apex:pageBlock>
```

**Here is the code**

```
public class MultipleOppRowEditing {

     //All property....

     public OpportunityLineItem oli{get;set;}
     public Id Id{get;set;}
     List<oliwrapper> oliList = new List<oliwrapper>();
     List<OpportunityLineItem> selectedOpportunityLineItem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

     //constructor....

     public MultipleOppRowEditing(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();

      }

     //displaying contact pageBlock table....

     public  List<oliwrapper> getoli() {

        for(OpportunityLineItem o: [select Id, product2.productcode,Unitprice,Quantity from OpportunityLineItem order by createdDate desc ])

              oliList.add(new oliwrapper(o));
              return oliList;
          }

       //all selected contacts...for edit...       
     public PageReference getSelected() {

         selectedOpportunityLineItem.clear();
         for(oliwrapper oppwrapper: oliList) 
            if(oppwrapper.selected == true)

            selectedOpportunityLineItem.add(oppwrapper.opp); 

            return null;
        }


     public List<OpportunityLineItem> GetSelectedoli(){

        if(selectedOpportunityLineItem.size()>0)
        return selectedOpportunityLineItem;
        else
       // ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select at least one opportunity.'));
        return null;
    } 

    //saving edited value...

      public PageReference tosave() { 
      if(selectedOpportunityLineItem.size()>0){

        update selectedOpportunityLineItem;
        PageReference MultiOppLineItemEdit=new PageReference('/apex/MultiOppLineItemEdit');
        MultiOppLineItemEdit.setRedirect(true);
        return MultiOppLineItemEdit;
        }
        else{
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select at least one OppLineItem.'));
         return null;
        }

       }

    //wrapper class...

    public class oliwrapper
    {
        public OpportunityLineItem opp{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public oliwrapper(OpportunityLineItem o)
        {
            opp = o;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Folkert:Thanks for you reply.I tried replacing as ProductCode ,but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Does it give a line number? Could you point us to which line of code throws the error? 
And have you also replace ProductCode in the VF page? `{!o.opp.product2.productcode}`

Comment: @Folkert:It does not give any line number ,and the error is reflected on the vf page ,the code got saved in the apex class.PFA Screen SHot

Comment: Try putting a debug log on your user and see if it gives a line in those logs.

Comment: you will have endless debugging problems if in your `oliWrapper` inner class you use a variable named `opp` to refer to an `OpportunityLineItem`. `opp` conveys notion of an opportunity, not a line item. The constructor in this inner class is equally afflicted

Answer (score 1):

Reason you are getting this is error is because you are querying relationship `Product2` that does not exist on OpportunityLineItem. The way product is linked to opp line item is via PriceBookEntry object.

Your query should look like this:

```
[SELECT Id, PricebookEntry.ProductCode, Unitprice, Quantity 
 FROM OpportunityLineItem 
 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to select a field that doesn't exist  in this query:

> [select Id, product2.productcode,Unitprice,Quantity from OpportunityLineItem order by createdDate desc ]

Can you try ProductCode instead of product2.productcode?

See the Object reference:
http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a lower case c on CreatedDate in your order by clause.

```
[select Id, product2.productcode,Unitprice,Quantity from OpportunityLineItem order by **c**reatedDate desc ]
```

Should be

```
[select Id, product2.productcode,Unitprice,Quantity from OpportunityLineItem order by **C**reatedDate desc ]
```

Also I think you need to include CreatedDate in your list fields to pull.

```
 [select Id, product2.productcode,Unitprice,Quantity,CreatedDate from OpportunityLineItem order by **C**reatedDate desc ]
```

Comment: welcome to SE. while posting any code you can format the code from edit toolbar. it will help to identify the code from rest of the text.